# How to redirect non-existing subdomain to another subdomain?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, subdomain, hosting

I have the following issues with subdomains in my hosting:

1. I have a subdomain, let's say shop.abc.com
2. Now I check on my log file, there are people accessing through **something**.shop.abc.com while subdomain **something** does not exist.
3. The subdomain "**something**" is not just "**something**" but rather random like **xyz**.shop.abc.com, **rex**.shop.abc.com, etc.
4. Another strange thing is that the rest of the URL is correct, for example, **rex4534**.abc.com/**cat1/article2**, "**cat1/article2**" is the correct URL segment.

Is it possible to redirect these non-existing subdomains to the correct subdomain while keeping the URL segment? Can it be done through .htaccess?

I put this line on .htaccess, but it doesn't work and causes a redirect if I access shop.abc.com

`RewriteRule ^ http://shop.abc.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply add  **" *.shop.abc.com"**  host and point it to where ever you want.

Comment: Silly me, why I didn't think of it in the first place. Thanks man, you saved me alot

Comment: You should have upvoted and approved answer as best return :)

Comment: It's not that I don't wanted to, but I cannot, my rank still too low to upvote. Had tried it several time :(